# how to delete the sms.db file from iPhone using xcode. is it possible the send me the source code

Tags: iphone, xcode

i want to delete the sms.db file from iPhone using xcode. is it possible to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Any application you write for the iPhone does not have access to anything outside its own sandbox.  The only way you'd be able to delete the SMS database using an app you've written is to write it for jailbroken iPhones.